# Auto approve facebook members using a web app that's connected to a database like MongoDB

Tags: facebook

What if I want to make a group only for specific students without manually accepting/refusing those who ask to join the group myself?

Assuming I've a database that has a number of passwords, and I've given one distinct password to every student, I want them to be automatically accepted if they ask to join and entered a correct password. I also do not want to allow them add/invite new members at all.

Is this even possible using FB API at the current time?

If so what topics/key_ideas/tags I must make a research about in order to create such a web app?

If there is any other way around, I'd love to hear it.

I am not a programmer, I just had few programming courses.

I'm new to alll and tring to learn something while solving a problem.

Comment: sounds like a Facebook Oauth login application to me.  User visits your site, gets redirected to facebook (into which they log in if not already), grants your app permission for various facebook access (you probably don't need more than username /email / however you identify them).  Anyone can go through that flow, but you can choose whom to allow into the app based on an allow list.  Note this doesn't involve distributing passwords, but the oauth flow *does* generate an oauth token for your app